# startForegroundService - unable to use setContentIntent + addAction?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, notifications, foreground

Unfortunately another question about my startForegroundService notification... I searched, really, I did:

I have a foreground service that is running perfectly. I would like to add a couple of actions to this notification. For one, make it so when the user clicks the notification they are sent to MainActivity as well as adding a "Quit" addAction.

Here is the snippet I am using to create the notification:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String channelId = getNotificationChannel(notificationManager);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_icon)
            .setContentTitle("My app")
            .setContentText("Background service is running...")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(13365, notification);
```

Using the above a notification shows up just fine, but click on it results in nothing. I also tried using addAction, also nothing. I am aware the syntax is a little bit different (....Action.Builder) when adding an addAction.

I am creating my notification in the onCreate handler of the foreground service. Running on SDK 26.

Can startForeground notifications have setContentIntent / addAction attached to them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved : I had the notification replaced elsewhere in my application and was not adding the intents there.

Doh!